# Why am I getting compile errors "<variable> not declared in this scope"?

Tags: c++, compilation

I was having some problems with my first C++ program (this one) awhile ago. Basically I am trying to do an assignment for intro to C++ class where the professor has taught us no syntax. Here is my code right now:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;
class Race
{
  public:
     void main()
     {

        executeRace();

        int randomMove()
        {
                srand(time(NULL));
                int randomInt = rand() % 100 + 1;
                return randomInt;
        }

        void executeRace()
        {
                int rabbitPosition = 1;
                int turtlePosition = 1;

                cout << "BANG!!!" << endl << "AND THEY'RE OFF!!!";

                while (rabbitPosition <=70 && turtlePosition <=70)
                {
                        printPositions(rabbitPosition, turtlePosition);

                        turtlePosition = turtleMoveSquares(turtlePosition);
                        rabbitPosition = rabbitMoveSquares(rabbitPosition);
                }

                printWinner(rabbitPosition, turtlePosition);

                tie(rabbitPosition, turtlePosition);
        }

        int turtleMoveSquares(int tPosition)
        {

                int turtleMove = randomMove();

                if(turtleMove >=1 && turtleMove <= 40)
                        tPosition = tPosition + 4;

                if(turtleMove >= 41 && turtleMove <= 50 )
                        tPosition = tPosition - 2;

                if(turtleMove >=51 && turtleMove <=100)
                        tPosition = tPosition + 2;

                if(tPosition < 1)
                        tPosition = 1;

                return tPosition;
        }

        int rabbitMoveSquares(int rabbitPosition)
        {

                int rabbitMove = randomMove();

                if(rabbitMove >=1 && rabbitMove <= 25)
                        rabbitPosition = rabbitPosition;

                if(rabbitMove >=26 && rabbitMove <= 55)
                        rabbitPosition = rabbitPosition + 10;

                if(rabbitMove >=56 && rabbitMove <=60)
                        rabbitPosition = rabbitPosition - 15;

                if(rabbitMove >=61 && rabbitMove <= 90)
                        rabbitPosition = rabbitPosition + 5;

                if(rabbitMove >=90 && rabbitMove <=100)
                        rabbitPosition = rabbitPosition - 3;

                if(rabbitPosition < 1)
                        rabbitPosition = 1;

                return rabbitPosition;
        }

        void printPositions(int rabbitPositions, int turtlePositions)
        {
                int turtleCount;
                int rabbitCount;
                int endCount;

                if(rabbitPositions == turtlePositions && rabbitPositions != 1)
                {
                        turtleCount = 1;

                        while(turtleCount < turtlePositions)
                        {
                                cout << "-";
                                turtleCount = turtleCount+1;
                        }
                        cout << "OUCH!";
                }

                else
                {
                        turtleCount = 1;
                        rabbitCount = 1;
                        endCount=1;

                        if(turtlePositions < rabbitPositions)
                        {
                                while(turtleCount < turtlePositions)
                                {
                                        cout <<  "-";
                                                turtleCount = turtleCount+1;
                                }
                                cout << "T";

                                while(rabbitCount < (rabbitPositions - turtlePositions))
                                {
                                        cout <<  "-";
                                        rabbitCount = rabbitCount+1;
                                }
                                cout << "H";

                        }

                        if(rabbitPositions < turtlePositions)
                        {
                                while(rabbitCount < rabbitPositions)
                                {
                                        cout << "-";
                                                rabbitCount = rabbitCount+1;
                                }
                                cout << "H";

                                while(turtleCount < (turtlePositions - rabbitPositions))
                                {
                                        cout << "-";
                                        turtleCount = turtleCount+1;
                                }
                                cout << "T";

                                cout << "\n";
                        }
                }
        }

        void printWinner(int rabbitPosition, int turtlePosition)
        {
                if(turtlePosition >= 70 && rabbitPosition < 70)
                {
                        cout << "TORTOISE WINS!!! YAY!!!\n";
                }
                else if(rabbitPosition >=70 && turtlePosition < 70)
                {
                        cout << "Hare wins. Yuch.\n";
                }
                else if(rabbitPosition >=70 && turtlePosition >=70)
                {
                        cout << "It's a tie\n";
                }
        }

        void tie(int turtlePosition, int rabbitPosition)
        {
                if(rabbitPosition >=70 && turtlePosition >=70)
                        executeRace();
        }

    }
};



int main()
{
  Race race;
  race.main();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and here are my errors on compile:

```
uxb3% g++ o- Race Race.cc
g++: o-: No such file or directory
g++: Race: No such file or directory
Race.cc: In member function 'void Race::main()':
Race.cc:14: error: 'executeRace' was not declared in this scope
Race.cc:17: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
Race.cc:24: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
Race.cc:44: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
Race.cc:64: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
Race.cc:90: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
Race.cc:153: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
Race.cc:169: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
```

Sorry to keep bothering you guys about this assignment, but it is my first and I am very, VERY frustrated and obsessed at the moment.

Comment: When you're calling g++, you should be using '-o' instead of 'o-', sans quotes, of course.

Comment: If you had made ONLY the changes I suggested in your previous question, I think you would have been fine. You're trying to do too much; you're getting ahead of where your course is.

Comment: My first C++ program was about 5 lines. Maybe try a hello world?

Answer (score 8):

You cannot have [functions inside your functions](http://i35.tinypic.com/2l8fbwl.jpg)*.

You probably want this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;
class Race
{
  public:
    int randomMove()
    {
            srand(time(NULL));
            int randomInt = rand() % 100 + 1;
            return randomInt;
    }

    void executeRace()
    {
            int rabbitPosition = 1;
            int turtlePosition = 1;

            cout << "BANG!!!" << endl << "AND THEY'RE OFF!!!";

            while (rabbitPosition <=70 && turtlePosition <=70)
            {
                    printPositions(rabbitPosition, turtlePosition);

                    turtlePosition = turtleMoveSquares(turtlePosition);
                    rabbitPosition = rabbitMoveSquares(rabbitPosition);
            }

            printWinner(rabbitPosition, turtlePosition);

            tie(rabbitPosition, turtlePosition);
    }

    int turtleMoveSquares(int tPosition)
    {

            int turtleMove = randomMove();

            if(turtleMove >=1 && turtleMove <= 40)
                    tPosition = tPosition + 4;

            if(turtleMove >= 41 && turtleMove <= 50 )
                    tPosition = tPosition - 2;

            if(turtleMove >=51 && turtleMove <=100)
                    tPosition = tPosition + 2;

            if(tPosition < 1)
                    tPosition = 1;

            return tPosition;
    }

    int rabbitMoveSquares(int rabbitPosition)
    {

            int rabbitMove = randomMove();

            if(rabbitMove >=1 && rabbitMove <= 25)
                    rabbitPosition = rabbitPosition;

            if(rabbitMove >=26 && rabbitMove <= 55)
                    rabbitPosition = rabbitPosition + 10;

            if(rabbitMove >=56 && rabbitMove <=60)
                    rabbitPosition = rabbitPosition - 15;

            if(rabbitMove >=61 && rabbitMove <= 90)
                    rabbitPosition = rabbitPosition + 5;

            if(rabbitMove >=90 && rabbitMove <=100)
                    rabbitPosition = rabbitPosition - 3;

            if(rabbitPosition < 1)
                    rabbitPosition = 1;

            return rabbitPosition;
    }

    void printPositions(int rabbitPositions, int turtlePositions)
    {
            int turtleCount;
            int rabbitCount;
            int endCount;

            if(rabbitPositions == turtlePositions && rabbitPositions != 1)
            {
                    turtleCount = 1;

                    while(turtleCount < turtlePositions)
                    {
                            cout << "-";
                            turtleCount = turtleCount+1;
                    }
                    cout << "OUCH!";
            }

            else
            {
                    turtleCount = 1;
                    rabbitCount = 1;
                    endCount=1;

                    if(turtlePositions < rabbitPositions)
                    {
                            while(turtleCount < turtlePositions)
                            {
                                    cout <<  "-";
                                            turtleCount = turtleCount+1;
                            }
                            cout << "T";

                            while(rabbitCount < (rabbitPositions - turtlePositions))
                            {
                                    cout <<  "-";
                                    rabbitCount = rabbitCount+1;
                            }
                            cout << "H";

                    }

                    if(rabbitPositions < turtlePositions)
                    {
                            while(rabbitCount < rabbitPositions)
                            {
                                    cout << "-";
                                            rabbitCount = rabbitCount+1;
                            }
                            cout << "H";

                            while(turtleCount < (turtlePositions - rabbitPositions))
                            {
                                    cout << "-";
                                    turtleCount = turtleCount+1;
                            }
                            cout << "T";

                            cout << "\n";
                    }
            }
    }

    void printWinner(int rabbitPosition, int turtlePosition)
    {
            if(turtlePosition >= 70 && rabbitPosition < 70)
            {
                    cout << "TORTOISE WINS!!! YAY!!!\n";
            }
            else if(rabbitPosition >=70 && turtlePosition < 70)
            {
                    cout << "Hare wins. Yuch.\n";
            }
            else if(rabbitPosition >=70 && turtlePosition >=70)
            {
                    cout << "It's a tie\n";
            }
    }

    void tie(int turtlePosition, int rabbitPosition)
    {
            if(rabbitPosition >=70 && turtlePosition >=70)
                    executeRace();
    }
};

int main()
{
  Race race;
  race.executeRace();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

*Unless dealing with higher-level languages, such as calculus, of course!

Answer (score 3):

Compiler options:

```
g++ -o Race Race.cc
```

You're also declaring functions within your Race::main function

```
class Race
{
  public:
     void main()
     {

        executeRace();
     } // <----- add this
```

Comment: when I do that I get errors:

Race.cc: In member function 'void Race::main()':
Race.cc:13: error: expected `;' before ':' token
Race.cc: At global scope:
Race.cc:175: error: expected unqualified-id before '}' token
Race.cc:175: error: expected declaration before '}' token

Comment: fixed 2 errors, but still get:

Race.cc: In member function 'void Race::main()':
Race.cc:13: error: expected `;' before ':' token

Comment: nvm, fixed it. I had a ':' instead of a ';' in one place. Compiled fine. Gonna try and run it now.

Comment: yep, the curse of the semicolons. You'll hate them at first, but come to love them. Then you will reach Enlightenment.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be using `gcc -o ...`, not `gcc o- ...`.

And, secondly, you can't define functions withing functions in C++.

Move the other function definition outside of your class `void main()`: specifically you need to move the second last brace before your `int main()` to immediately before `int randomMove()`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to pull out the various functions which are at the moment included in the main() function defined in Race (inside its braces).

Select them, Ctrl-X (Cut), move to above the main() declaration, Ctrl-V (Paste). Reformat. Recompile.

Comment: Or he can just move the ending brace up.  Also, copy/paste are editor specific.  =]